# Closing down a Netty UDP Server

Tags: java, udp, datagram, netty

I have a written a very simple UDP Server using Netty - it quite happily binds itself and accepts messages, but I can'y figure out how to unbind it.

Am I missing something, or does Netty not expose the necessary APIs to unbind a server?

**Edit**

Here is the code I am using to bind the server:

```
DatagramChannelFactory f = new NioDatagramChannelFactory(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
ConnectionlessBootstrap b = new ConnectionlessBootstrap(f);

ChannelPipeline p = b.getPipeline();
p.addLast("encoder", new StringEncoder());
p.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder());
p.addLast("logic",   this);

chan = b.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

netty provides many entry points to setting up a server, I don't know which one you've used.

You should be able to simply `.unbind` (or .close) the `Channel` you get back from [ServerBootstrap.bind](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/netty/freezone/api/3.1/org/jboss/netty/bootstrap/ServerBootstrap.html#bind())

Comment: I have edited the question to show the code I'm using - seems like .close() does exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: With UDP it should be ConnectionlessBootstrap and not ServerBootstrap (which is for TCP).